# Proof writing involving functions: Injective and Surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Given two sets that have the same cardinal number

Example:
\begin{align*}
A & = \{1, 4\}\\
B & = \{1, 2\}
\end{align*}
How would you prove that the function from $A$ to $B$ is **always** injective and surjective **AND not**.... injective but not surjective or surjective but not injective.

My proof: Since the cardinal number of $A$ and $B$ is $n(A) = n(B)$. Then thus, inj$(\beta) \wedge$ surj$(\beta)$. Therefore by definition, bij $(\beta)$. So the function from $A$ to $B$ is always bijective.

Is this correct? Other ways to prove this?

Comment: Sets are not injective, functions are injective. Do you mean that any function that is injective or surjective function $A\to B$ is necessarily both injective and surjective?

Comment: This sounds confused. Two sets have the same cardinality given that one can show that there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry. yes the function from A to B. I want to prove that if a fuction has the same cardinal number then it has to be bijective

Comment: That it is impossible for it to be: injective and not surjective or surjective and not injective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to prove is simply not true. First of all a function from $A$ to $B$ does not have to be injective and surjective. Take for example the set's in your example and have $f:A\to B$ such that $f(1)=f(4)=2$, clearly not injective or surjective.

Also it's possible for an injection to not be surjective and a surjection to be not injective. For the first case just take the mapping from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = x$, clearly an injection that is not a surjection. The other way around from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ such that $f(n) = |n|$, a surjection that's not injective.

What you could try to prove is that for finite sets with the same cardinality that a map $f:A\to B$ is injective is equvialent to it being surjective.

But if a mapping $f:A\to B$ is injective we have that $|A| \le |f(A)|$, but $f(A)\subseteq B$ so $|f(A)|\le|B|$ so we have:

$$|A| \le |f(A)| \le |B| = |A|$$

And since $|f(A)| = |B|$, $f(A)\subseteq B$ and $B$ is finite we must have that $f(A) = B$, that is $f$ is surjective.

The opposite is proved in similar way.

Comment: My question was terribly reworded but you were able to answer it.  Thanks.